# Error calling GET /3/Jobs h2o model training Error on large data

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, predictive, h2o4gpu

i am trying to build model on a large data(2 millions transaction data) and getting below error.Thee is no progress in model building in progress bar and after some time job stops with below error.We are running this in single node and h2o is not distributed.
Please suggest is this is related to memory issue.Like If we have 20 GB training data then how much memory,heap size should be given to h2o?
Does all the complete training frame stores in heap memory?

```
Error fetching job '$03010a010d6832d4ffffffff$_9bf0e32df1dba1c2d24eb8a513f47a4'
Error calling GET /3/Jobs/%2403010a010d6832d4ffffffff%24_9bf0e32df1dba1c2d24eb8a513f47a4
HTTP connection failure: status=error, code=503, error=Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

Thanks
Deepti

Comment: The `error=Service Temporarily Unavailable` part of the message suggests something different than a memory issue.

Comment: @desertnaut how much memory we should allocate to h2o..Does all training data in h2o reside in heap memory?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that an H2O cluster goes down due to out-of-memory and your client loses communication with it. You would need to review the H2O logs to determine the error/cause.

A general rule of thumb is to have about 4x memory of your dataset. See the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/faq/general-troubleshooting.html#occasionally-i-receive-an-out-of-memory-error-is-there-a-method-based-on-the-trees-depth-cross-validations-that-is-used-to-determine-how-much-memory-is-needed-to-store-the-model). In your case, you should have about 80GB needed to handle data manipulation and modeling.